# jQuery POST working but no response

Tags: jquery

Let me post code first

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select[name="id"]').change(function(){
    $.post("http://www.example.com/api/getval.php",
      {
        id:$(this).val(),
      },
      function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      });
});
});
</script>
```

Data is being POSTed, I'm sure. But it appears no response.

I need your suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the dev tools (Chrome) or Firebug (Firefox) to see what's going aross?

Comment: could be because of a parse error, check your browser console, check the response status also

Comment: Since you have the full URL (with hostname), there may be cross-domain resource sharing issue as well.

Comment: Which browser ? You cannot have `,` (comma) in last `key:value` pair of object in few browsers

Comment: what is outputting in `alert()`?

Comment: Okay, going to answer you all at once.
Tried in latest version of Chrome & FF.
No Alert at all, but data is being sent.
Just tried with removing comma mentioned by @Jai but no luck.

Comment: What response are you looking? Have you tried with `getJson`?

Comment: @NoviceCoder yes you can use POST but this way as i suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing `,` here:

```
  {
    id:$(this).val(),
  }, //-------------^-----this one
```

If you are getting `json` in response you can try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('select[name="id"]').change(function(){
      $.post("http://www.example.com/api/getval.php", {id:$(this).val()}, function(data,status){
         alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      }, "json");
   });
});
```

And i suggest you to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.

```
console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
```

Comment: Works in few browsers. I guess chrome and firefox.